# C++ multiplatform library to playback /record audio (.wav, .ogg)

Tags: c++, audio-recording, multiplatform, audio-player

I have a multiplatform application and want to add audio annotations functionality.
I am looking for audio playback /recording library that is:

- multiplatform (Windows, Linux, Mac)
- simple and fast to integrate into existing project
- do not use cygwin for Windows build
- has C++ bindings

I saw *gstreamer* but I have the feeling that is it too advanced for my simple use cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look into [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)? That should be able to [play OGG files](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL_mixer%3aTutorials%3aPlaying_an_OGG_Music_File) and [WAV files](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL_mixer%3aTutorials%3aPlaying_a_WAV_Sound_File).

Answer (score 1):

I have used [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net), but it seems currently broken for recording on Macs. If you can record from your device without it, it has nice file-handling features.

[PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) is used in a high-profile sound app, Audiomulch.

I haven't used [RtAudio](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/), but I've used projects that use it. It handles JACK, CoreAudio, ALSA, OSS, DirectSound, and ASIO.

[libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) is a common dependency for projects that need to deal with audio files as an alternative to sox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) fits the bill. Format support is near infinite and it has proven its worth. Unfortunately, it will need a UNIX-like shell to build. You don't need Cygwin though, but can use MSYS for that, for which you can find an up-to-date binary distribution [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/). It may be overkill for simple audio (record) functionality, but you mention the ability to support different formats. You cannot *compile* ffmpeg with Visual C++ compilers, but you can use it once the library is built by GCC or other C99 compliant compiler.